# Is it possible for the admin of the app to see the Firebase SMS verification code?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

As we are developing an application used by **farmers mostly in remote places** around the globe, There is an issue in logging in using OTP if it is possible the admin can see the OTP (mostly not receiving OTP due to network issues), we will be login at the other end (admin) and make it possible for the users to use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Firebase Authentication doesn't let you see the code. You'll have to build a custom solution for it.

Comment: sir can i get any solutions based on it

Comment: One viable solution is to use Cloud functions and send the message yourself using any 3rd party service. But again it's like implementing this whole system yourself.